# how can i use ratchet websocket in php to connect bybit websocket and get real data in html side?

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet, bybit

I use ratchet to connect bybit api to receive data as below and now I want to see json response on html side as response receives from bybit api ,

```
include "textalk/vendor/autoload.php";
$client = new WebSocket\Client("wss://stream-testnet.bybit.com/contract/usdt/public/v3", ['timeout' => 300]);
$json='{"req_id": "100001", "op": "subscribe" ,"args": [
        "orderbook.1.BTCUSDT",
        "orderbook.1.ETHUSDT",
        "orderbook.1.ADAUSDT",
        "orderbook.1.TRXUSDT",
        "orderbook.1.XRPUSDT",
        "orderbook.1.BNBUSDT",
        "orderbook.1.SOLUSDT",
        "orderbook.1.ARBUSDT",
        "orderbook.1.DOGEUSDT",
        "orderbook.1.C98USDT"
    ]}';
$client->text($json);
while ($client->isConnected()) {
    try {
        $message = $client->receive();
         print_r($message);
       // $decoded_json = json_decode($message, true);
       // echo $decoded_json['topic'].' '. $decoded_json['data']['s'];
        echo "\n";
        
        
 
      } catch (\WebSocket\ConnectionException $e) {
        // Possibly log errors
        print_r("Error: ".$e->getMessage());
        echo "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: why not do it clientside instead of in php just to push to clientside?

Comment: i need to merge some data with received json.